# Shortest transatlantic flight from Europe to somewhere, so that continental US can be reached by land (with possible ferry)

Tags: air-travel, usa, canada, europe, iceland

I am trying to find a route from Helsinki, Finland to Washington, DC, USA so that the air time is minimized, as the person travelling is afraid of an air travel. Assume, visas are not a problem.

Basically, I am looking for a shortest non-stop transatlantic flight originating in Europe and landing somewhere, from where Washington, DC can be reached by land (with possible ferry).

It seems there are 2 possible routes:

- land/ferry to Iceland, then Keflavik -> (Greenland, ferry) -> Canada -> Land to US
- Land to London, then LHR -> Canada -> Land to US

Specific subquestions:

1. What is the absolute shortest flight time from KEF to any point in Canada?
2. What is the absolute shortest flight time from London to any point in Canada?
3. I was not able to find any regular transportation between points in Greenland and points in Canada. Did I miss something?
4. What are good points of embarkation in Canada? Halifax? St John's?

Any other possible routes I missed?

I am seeking a factual basis to decide between:

- investing in air-travel phobia therapy and attempting regular HEL->JFK
- travelling via cruise liner
- travelling via freight vessel
- attempting to minimize air travel time by covering some part by land.

However, this question's scope is limited to just minimizing air travel time.

**TL;DR**

1. The shortest flight would be either KEF->YHZ (Halifax) 4:30,
       seasonal
2. Second shortest (but much more easy accessible from Europe) is DUB->YYT (St John's) 4:55, seasonal

and thank everyone who contributed to the whole spectrum of the answers collected

Comment: Have you looked at repositioning cruises? In the fall, there are transits from European ports to the US . [For example, Royal Caribbean: August 26, from Copenhagen to Boston, visiting Oslo, Kristiansand, Reykjavik, Akureyri,  Halifax](http://www.repositioncruises.com/royal-caribbean-repositioning-cruises/)

Comment: I assume going the long way around isn't an option?  You could do a *lot* of it by train, iirc.

Comment: Based on my experience with phobia, I will venture that the actual duration of the flight will be less significant than you think.

Comment: Besides cruises doesn't some container/freight companies allow a few passengers on their ships? Have no idea if it is cheaper or more expensive than cruises. I've heard the crew love passengers as nothing much at all happens on board and at least it is new people to talk to.

Comment: There are no ferries between Greenland and anywhere, and no scheduled flights other than to Iceland and Denmark.

Comment: I would consider minimizing the time of _conscious_ flight by trying to get a prescription for a good sleeping pill.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54878/discussion-on-question-by-mzu-shortest-transatlantic-flight-from-europe-to-somew).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Reykjavik to Halifax (Nova Scotia) is showing as 18:05 to 19:40 according to [Icelandair's summer timetable](http://www.icelandair.co.uk/information/travel-guide/timetable/), page 23.

That isn't really 1h35 minutes of course, thanks to time zones. The timetable shows Reykjavik on GMT while Halifax is on GMT-3 thanks to Daylight Savings.

So, 4 hours 35 minutes from Reykjavik to Halifax.

Edit : when I'm calling the airport Reykjavik I'm quoting the Icelandair brochure "From REYKJAVÍK KEF" - indeed Reykjavik's main airport is a few miles away at Keflavik but if Icelandair are happy to call it Reykjavik that's good enough for me.

And indeed I didn't cover the means of getting to Reykjavik : the obvious route is the [Smyril Line](http://www.smyrilline.com/sailing-schedule/schedule-2017), who run a weekly service from Denmark via the Faeroe Islands.

I can't comment on the Icelandic bus network though one commenter points out it may be fragmentary, and may need a taxi to get some joined-up transport going.

And after several days crossing the North Atlantic even on such a large and modern ship as the [Norrona](http://www.smyrilline.com/norrona), and several hundred km on Iceland's roads, the actual flight will probably come as a blissful relief.

Comment: Thanks. This gives the ballpark idea. Can it be further reduced?

Comment: I have also checked any reasonable airport, but this seems indeed to be the shortest flight. It is a seasonal route however, and only operated by Icelandair from June 3rd to October 15th (2017). Flights from London are in general 1,5 to 2 hours longer to any point in the area.

Comment: Well you'll probably fly over Gander, in Newfoundland, but (a) pretty much nothing international lands there nowadays except for emergencies (which the whole point is to avoid) and (b) I suspect the only onward travel would be another flight.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, there is LHR->YYT (St. Johns, NewFoundland) by Air Canada, but originating from LHR adds 1h20m to the flight time

Comment: Too bad the concorde is not flying anymore. Would've been even shorter

Comment: That should be Keflavík, not Reykavík.  There *are* intercontinental flights from Reykavík; they are to Greenland, which is in North America (but without a land-based connection to continental US).

Comment: Also, be aware that ferries Denmark-Iceland arrive at Seyðisfjörður which is poorly connected to the Icelandic bus network and more than 700 km from Keflavík; if you're lucky you can hitch-hike to Akureyi from where buses to Reykjavík are far more frequent, but you need to allow for at least two days to reach Keflavík from Seyðisfjörður.

Comment: @gerrit many (most?) metropolitan airports are actually outside the limits of the city they serve; we never correct those who say they're flying to Paris or Amsterdam, though in the former case we might ask for clarification.  As Brian says, if Icelandair calls it Rekjavik then why shouldn't we?

Comment: @phoog There are two airports; one is in Keflavík and is called Keflavík International Airport / Keflavíkurflugvöllur (KEF), the other is in Reykjavík and is called Reykjavík Airport / Reykjavíkurflugvöllur / RKV.  The situation near Paris or London is different as all those airports officially have Paris or London in their names, no matter how far from the nominal city they are.  "Stockholm Airport Västerås" and "Frankfurt Airport Hahn" claim to be near Stockholm and Frankfurt but aren't; Keflavík International Airport makes no such claim.

Comment: I guess the difference is that Brian goes by what the company Icelandair uses, and I go by what the airport officially uses.

Comment: Still, I don't think Keflavik is unique. Dulles and Newark come to mind (although I don't think any of NYC's airports has "New York" the name, even though two of them *are* in the city limits).

Comment: @BrianDrummond Gander is commonly used by _private_ transatlantic flights, by small planes which don't have the range or other requirements to make a longer, more southerly crossing in a single takeoff and landing. Nevertheless it has full immigration and customs services for any size of passenger or cargo flight.

Answer (score 20):

If flight time is truly of the highest consideration, then [this blog](https://delightandinspire.com/2015/05/28/how-to-get-from-russia-to-alaska-across-the-bering-strait/) details one person's travel around the world desiring the least possible flight time in doing so.

Three options are proposed, but I can't confirm whether they are still current:

> 1. Fly from Vladivostok (or Khabarovsk) to Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky, then get a flight from Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky to Anchorage, Alaska,
>      with Yakutia (www.yakutia.aero), a Russian airline. It’s about a 3
>      hour flight and goes every Saturday from 11th July to 29th August as
>      it’s a seasonal flight.
> 2. Travel from Vladivostok to Provideniya, the furthest airport towards the Bering Strait, from there, you can charter a plane from
>      Bering Air, an Alaskan company.
> 3. You can walk across the Bering Strait when it is frozen solid, however, it’s about 53 miles of ice, after 800 miles of no roads

Perhaps it may be worth corresponding with the author to further investigate these options. I'm envious of someone who tries option 3!

Comment: I love your answer but it's a misconception that the Bering Strait freezes completely; there are channels of open water which, on occasion, get clogged with chunks of ice. So you could jump from one to another, if not a bit of swimming. Russia won't allow Westerners in that area to attempt the crossing and the two who made from Alaska were arrested and deported.

Comment: @Dorothy Perhaps you could count jumping from one ice floe to another to sum up to the amount of "air travel time" required :)

Comment: #1 and #2 look very promising: reducing flight time to just 3 hours. I did not realize there are regular flights Siberia->Alaska

Comment: @mzu The ~10000km trip fromo Helsinki to Vladivostok, and ~ 7000km from Anchorage to Washington DC might be a bit of a disadvantage there. Would make one hell of a trip, that's for sure, although I'm not certain I'd want to do it both ways.

Comment: @pnuts, I agree, but this answer provided me quite a new line of thought, so I would leave it here.

Comment: @mzu It's a three hour flight from Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky to Anchorage, but to get to Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky you're probably going to have to fly. There's no roads to it and I don't think there's any regular ferry service. Even if there is a ferry, it would be faster and probably cheaper to book a transatlantic cruise on the Queen Mary 2. Provideniya is even worse, also only accessible by air, and even more remote.

Comment: Instead of **flying** from Helsinki to Vladivostok, you could travel there by train (Helsinki - Moscow, Moscow - Vladivostok). Traveling with the Transsiberian Railway is certainly an interesting experience, but keep in mind that you would spend about a week on a train.

Comment: @Dorothy, AFAIR, the pair traveling the world on foot was arrested because they missed the designated Russian immigration checkpoint because of the snowstorm. Otherwize, they had it all arranged with US and Russian authorities.

Comment: @DP_ a week on a train is fun. However getting from Vladivostok to Petropavlovsk using some sort of ship/ferry is going to be problematic.

Answer (score 16):

St. John's seems like the best jumping-off point, as the easternmost major airport in North America.  If having the shortest flight possible is really the goal, Air Canada has a flight from St. John's to London Heathrow,  5:05 eastbound, 5:50 westbound.   In summer only, WestJet does St. John's to Dublin, 4:30 eastbound, 4:55 westbound.   Here's information on the [London flight](http://onemileatatime.boardingarea.com/2014/06/03/shortest-transatlantic-flight-goes-year-round/) and the [Dublin flight](http://www.eurocheapo.com/blog/creative-options-for-flying-to-europe.html).   One can get from Dublin to mainland Europe by a combination of land and sea much more easily than one can get from Reykjavik to mainland Europe - see for example [the seat61 guide to Ireland](http://www.seat61.com/Ireland.htm) and [to Iceland](http://www.seat61.com/Iceland.htm).

Comment: I like this answer as much as KEF->YHZ (Halifax) answer above, if not better.

Comment: Note that St. John's does not have scheduled rail service.  Accessing the North American continent from there via ground transportation would require a 14-hour bus (coach) ride to Port-Aux-Basques, a 7-hour ferry crossing from Port-Aux-Basques to North Sydney, and a 4–5-hour bus ride from North Sydney to Truro.  (Additional ferry connections exist during the summer, but do not shave off that much time.)  The person in question would have to weigh the level of their phobia, but the trade-off here is basically 1–2 hours of additional flying time vs. two additional **days** of ground travel.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert And, in particular, two additional days of ground travel which, on the return journey, will mostly be spent thinking, "Crap, I have to get on another plane." It's hard to believe that this absolute focus on minimizing time in the air is the right approach.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, in this case I will likely meet them there and drive them all the way to DC. Small adventure included

Comment: @DavidRicherby, not an issue in this particular case.

Comment: @mzu:  Then you are a good friend indeed.  However, keep in mind that the driving time is substantial (17 hours to from DC to Halifax, and 38 hours to St. John's, according to Google Maps).

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, 38 hours both ways. As I told, adventure included.

Comment: There's also [Paris to Saint Pierre](http://airsaintpierre.com/en/paris/).  It's a bit longer (6:30 westbound, 5:35 eastbound), but even more of an adventure to take a domestic transatlantic flight :)

Comment: @DavidRicherby It's not, but it's great fun to figure it out (:

Answer (score 8):

From summer 2024 (and previously between 2012 and 2014), there are seasonal flights between Greenland and Nunavut, which means you can cross the Atlantic with a series of flights not much longer than 3 hours:

- Ottawa to Iqaluit (domestic flight Canada) is 3 hours 5 minutes.
- Iqaluit (Canada) to Nuuk (Greenland).  Most difficult bit.  Although [announced to restart in summer 2024](https://www.rcinet.ca/eye-on-the-arctic/2023/10/18/air-greenland-to-restart-nuuk-iqaluit-link-in-summer-2024/), a previous attempt only lasted three seasons (2012-2014), so let's see how long it survives this time.  The flight is announced to take two hours.
- Nuuk (Greenland) to Keflavík (Iceland) direct, once weekly, is 3 hours 10 minutes.

Although the total adds up to more than the other alternatives, each segment is shorter than the 4½ hours for Keflavík – Halifax, and there's a lot to see on the way.  It only works in summer.  It's going to be expensive (>$5000).  Keflavík — Halifax is far cheaper and probably a better option, but I'm just putting it here as an adventurous alternative.

Comment: Scheduled Nuuk–Iqaluit service was [discontinued in 2015.](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/north/air-greenland-cuts-nuuk-iqaluit-scheduled-flights-in-2015-1.2985006)  Charters may still be available, though.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Hm.  Pity.  Edited for clarification.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert They [trying again starting in 2024](https://www.rcinet.ca/eye-on-the-arctic/2023/10/18/air-greenland-to-restart-nuuk-iqaluit-link-in-summer-2024/)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to avoid flying entirely, you can.  The [Queen Mary 2](https://www.cunard.com/en-gb/cruise-destinations/transatlantic-cruises) still sails between Southampton and New York or Fort Lauderdale about once a month.  Prices start at about £1400 one way for a couple sharing a double cabin, which includes food.  I would be surprised if you can find a cheaper way of crossing the Atlantic without flying.  Getting from Helsinki to Southampton by train and boat is fairly straightforward.  The only time I did it, I used the Turku–Stockholm ferry, and then travelled via Copenhagen, Cologne, Brussels and London.  (I find [Deutsche Bahn's website](https://int.bahn.de/en/) very useful for planning such journeys.)  New York to Washington is one of few routes in the US that is well served by train, using the [Acela](https://www.amtrak.com/acela-train), which is as close as it gets to high-speed rail in the North America.